# CarrierWave transaction Rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, carrierwave, fog

I've been trying to hook up Carrierwave for image uploads, using fog and the google cloud platform for storage. However my basic implementation is getting rolled back every time it tries to hit the database via `users#update`. I have been unsuccessful in trying to troubleshoot this issue, any help is much appreciated. Rails version is `5.0.1`

**I have fallen back to using carrierwave's local storage to try and debug this problem, but I'm still having the same rollback issue. I have updated the files to reflect this.

**Update: The error message the active record model gives is `Avatar translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error`.

**Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'mini_magick'
```

**avatar_uploader.rb:**

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :display do
    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [80, 80]
  end

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :check_authorization, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :set_user

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Something went wrong. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def check_authorization
      unless current_user.id == params[:id].to_i
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
    end

end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :meetings
  has_many :action_items
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :comments

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>

<%= form_for(@user, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>

  <%= f.submit "Save Change" %>

<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: could you include the server log where is doing the query that is being rolled back? thanks

Comment: I just added the server log, although I'm not sure how helpful it will be. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, could you try including the extension whitelist as suggested in this post ? thanks Fabrizio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968777/why-when-uploading-a-file-using-carrierwave-in-rails-4-i-get-rollback-transacti

Answer (score 2):

There was a problem with my Imagemagick install. I re-installed and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please include the following lines in your AvatarUploader and restart the server

```
def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
```

I am quoting the following [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30968777/why-when-uploading-a-file-using-carrierwave-in-rails-4-i-get-rollback-transacti) from [edudepetris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956873/edudepetris)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the `store_dir` method and tried using `storage :file` just to see if it was fog causing me problems, but even then I was getting the same rollback problem.

Comment: @HarryZumwalt maybe you did not notice. But I saw that you did not include ' config.fog_provider = 'fog/google' ' which based on the Carrierwave github guide is required. You can see it in my post

Comment: Hi yes, I added that line along with the accompanying gem with no success. However like I said, I completley bypassed fog and tried just using carrierwave local storage with `storage :file` while removing `storage :fog`. Carrierwave is still being rolled back, which means the error can't be related to fog. Thanks

Comment: I also just updated my initial question to reflect my current issue.

Comment: Hi thanks again. Yeah I had already seen that post, he is actually advising the OP to re-comment the lines / remove them. I have tried it with the whitelist though and experience the same issue.

Comment: If I log @user.errors.full_messages to my console it gives me `Avatar translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error`. What could mini_magik be choking on?

Comment: @HarryZumwalt disable it. it should be connected to the different image versions `  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [200,200]
  end`